# Circuit giving values on both AC and DC

Tags: ac, dc, generator, solenoid, electromagnet

I have a generator stopper which works on 220 volt AC (in India 220 volt AC is normal supply) and has an electromagnet which pulls up a lever and the generator is stopped.

It works perfectly when the mains supply is given, but when I give supply thorough my UPS it doesn't work, while the same voltage is given from UPS also.

I opened up the stopper and tried to check what final voltage it supplies to the electromagnet after passing the circuit, as the mains wire first goes to a circuit and then to the magnet and I got reading from multimeter in both AC and DC.  In AC it read as 80 volts and in DC it read around 150 volts.

How is this possible? My multimeter is also fine as I tested it in other things.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Image source: [Bristol Watch](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/basic_ac_rectification.htm).*

If the DC supply is a simple rectifier then it is full-wave rectified DC. The DC voltage is not steady so it has an AC component as well. Your meter will read both.

Because you have supplied no details on the current required by the "stopper" and no details on the UPS we cannot answer that part of the question.